# How to find out which R version a package require.

Tags: r, bioconductor

I tried to install [this package](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/chipseqDB/) which was built with Bioconductor (R): 3.1 (3.2.1). However, I got the following error:

```
Bioconductor version 3.1 (BiocInstaller 1.18.4), ?biocLite for help
* DONE (BiocInstaller)

The downloaded source packages are in
    \u2018/tmp/Rtmp6YGmfv/downloaded_packages\u2019
Bioconductor version 3.1 (BiocInstaller 1.18.4), ?biocLite for help
> workflowInstall("chipseqDB")
Installing package into \u2018/home/lorencm/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2\u2019
(as \u2018lib\u2019 is unspecified)
Warning message:
package \u2018chipseqDB\u2019 is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

Next, I failed to update R with the below command:

```
> install.packages("installr") # install
Installing package into \u2018/home/lorencm/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2\u2019
(as \u2018lib\u2019 is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package \u2018installr\u2019 is not available (for R version 3.2.1) 
>
```

How to find out which R version a package require or the lib PATH is wrong?

Comment: Usually it's stated under "Depends R (>= version)" like here: http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/cn.mops.html Mysteriously there seems not to be such a page for chipseqDB (I get an error message). Optimally you should contact the maintainers of the package.

Comment: I think it is weird that there are several "\u" in your code, is something wrong with your encoding?

Answer (score 2):

The package `installr` is only available for Windows. 
You are using a linux OS.

See

> OS_type:  windows

at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html

To update the R version on your redhat system, see the installation instructions at https://cran.r-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is working now. There was a problem on the Bioconductor site earlier. Try it again.